# SQL Data consuming - SharePoint 2007 Timer job

Tags: sharepoint, moss, sharepoint-2007

Which is the most SQL data consuming SharePoint 2007 timer job except the crawling?

Answer (score 1):

I guess it depends... for us it has been the "Database Statistics" job.  It put a real hurt on our performance and we ended up disabling.  Not to say that we do not do a database statistics update, we just had our DBA write one that is better tuned for our enviornment.

Below is a list of all OOB SharePoint timer jobs

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc678870.aspx

Comment: Talking about database statistics, take a note from a link you provided: "If you have not installed Windows SharePoint Services 3.0 with SP2, the job updates the query optimization statistics by performing a full scan of key tables every time that it runs, which can be resource-intensive."
Maybe that's solved :)